# How to customize Api endpoint for Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am currently building Azure functions using VS Code on my local now.
There are 9 azure functions and all of them are placed in the root folder.
Now, I really want to make my project structure like this.

- Feature A

  - Function 1
  - Function 2
  - Function 3
- Feature B

  - Function 1
  - Function 2
  - Function 3
- Feature C

  - Function 1
  - Function 2
  - Function 3

I added routePrefix field to host.json.
But it just modifies the prefix url of all azure functions in my project.
And it is not helpful.

Please help me to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You use Azure APIM Service to customize the Function APIs endpoint as you required.

As per my understanding, your function project has 9 Function APIs where you want to separate them into 3 categories such as Feature A, B and C should contain each 3 of the Function APIs.

Create APIM Service which is near to your end users or in the location of Function App exist in the Azure Portal and you can add the APIs in the below way where you can easily identify the Function APIs belongs to which category named as Feature A, B and C.

- You can execute them via Azure Portal, browser, APIM Developer Portal and also Postman.
- You can restrict the users in accessing those APIs from the APIM Service.

**Note**: As of now, to show your requirement I have removed APIM Subscription key for accessing the APIs URL.

[image]

**Steps**:

1. Import required APIs from the APIM Service > API > - Name it accordingly like

[image]

2. You can remove/add specific Operations level in the imported APIs if you want:
   [image]
3. You can utilize the Products, Subscriptions features from the APIM Service for restricting the users to access the APIs and more info on this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-add-products?tabs=azure-portal).